# crash after UIAlertViewDelegate's clickedButtonAtIndex with message [MPMoviePlayerViewController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller, uialertview

I just want to dismiss `UIAlertView` but I can't with a strange bug for some days...

After tapping cancel button on `UIAlertView`, Codes below works.

```
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex 
{
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:buttonIndex animated:YES];
}
```

But After passing these lines, it makes crash with message below:

```
[MPMoviePlayerViewController isKindOfClass:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x27f590
```

On the same view, I embed

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.view
[self.view addSubview:vc.moviePlayer.view];
```

Does Anybody know what happend?
I use ARC, iOS5.1. If you need more information, I do add them.

Thank you in advance.

**more info:**

I set breakpoints on all methods in my code.
And I made sure that it crashes after `clickedButtonAtIndex`...

codes for calling UIAlertView show are

```
-(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    self.alert = hoge; // set delegate = self
    [self.alert show];
}
```

after calling them, `viewDidAppear`'s called.
There are codes for enbedding `vc.moviePlayer.view` like

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *vc;
vc = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:hogeURL];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(finishPreload:)
                                             name:MPMediaPlaybackIsPreparedToPlayDidChangeNotification
                                           object:vc];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(finishPlayback:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:vc];

vc.view.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 320, 440);

vc.moviePlayer.allowsAirPlay = YES;
vc.moviePlayer.shouldAutoplay = NO;
vc.moviePlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
vc.moviePlayer.useApplicationAudioSession = NO;

[vc.moviePlayer.view setTag:310];

[self.view addSubview:vc.moviePlayer.view];
```

My app has 3 tabs, 2 of them's embed `MPMoviePlayerViewController.moviePlayer.view`. Method called in the other tabs's controller are `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear` only.

Comment: The problem is not with UIAlertView, it's the functions which gets called after the cancel button is pressed. In your code put a break point and check where exactly it crashes. and show us where you are initiating MPMoviePlayerViewController, In code are you checking any instance for being a MPMovieViewController by using isKinfOfClass method?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I added more information in my question. If you need more information, Please write about it. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that your `MPMoviePlayerController` instance is deallocated after `viewDidAppear`. I think you should set `vc` as a property or instance variable of the View Controller so that it persists throughout the lifetime of the View Controller.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I solved it by setting vc as a property like @property (strong, nonatomic) MPMoviePlayerViewController *vc.